# PHPUnit reports no tests run, then runs tests

Tags: phpunit

I have an interesting (but ultimately harmless) problem: PHPUnit will report that no tests were executed, and then proceed to read the config file and run the tests, giving an output as below.

It would appear that PHPUnit is exiting and then resuming for some reason. I've looked through my bootstrap process and log files I can't see anything which would cause PHPUnit to exit (an exception or exit statement or the like).

The tests are being run from the tests directory, using the PHPUnit phar: `php ../phpunit.phar -c phpunit.xml`

**Has anybody seen this behaviour before? What was the problem?** Ultimately, this isn't harming anything at all, I'm just curious as to what's going on.

```
PHPUnit 3.7.34 by Sebastian Bergmann.



Time: 2.18 seconds, Memory: 23.50Mb

No tests executed!
PHPUnit 3.7.34 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from /path/to/phpunit.xml

.............................................................   61 / 2630 (  2%)
.............................................................  122 / 2630 (  4%)
.. and so on ..
```

The configuration files also appears to be OK, since the tests do run.

```
<phpunit
    colors="true"
    bootstrap="/path/to/application/bootstrap.php"
    backupGlobals="false"
>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Unit Tests">
            <directory>./</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to run PHPUnit with `--debug` to see whats going on.